# Has any Peer-Reviewed Double Blind Study been made on any vaccine regarding efficacy?

Tags: medical-science, vaccines, safety

I can not even find one Peer-Reviewed Double Blind Study of any vaccine.

Can you point out some studies for me, if they are available?

Comment: Search on Google for Polio. EVERY vaccine has peer-reviewed studies done before it is approved, then more come after. Vote to close (subjective and argumentative).

Comment: @Daniel I suggest you run a quick [search on PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=vaccine%20efficacy) before you make such a bold statement.

Comment: Please formulate this as a question, not as a statement. In this form the question is likely to be closed. You're just stating your conclusion (that vaccines don't work) already in your question, this is not a forum, you're supposed to ask questions, not just declare your opinion.

Comment: I said Peer-Reviewed **Double Blind** Study. There is a huge difference.

Comment: Edited to make less inflammatory. Daniel - please use the comments only for talking about the question. We have a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) for extended discussion.

Comment: Demanding that a double blind study be performed would be an unethical practice.  You realize that it would intentionally expose subjects who were getting the non-effective vaccine to potentially deadly diseases.  Of course, since when have ethical standards ever applied to anti-vaxers?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- [Immunogenicity and reactogenicity of a 13-valent-pneumococcal conjugate vaccine administered at 2, 4, and 12 months of age: a double-blind randomized active-controlled trial](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21155091).
- [Immunogenicity of bivalent types 1 and 3 oral poliovirus vaccine: a randomised, double-blind, controlled trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20980048)
- [Efficacy of pentavalent rotavirus vaccine against severe rotavirus gastroenteritis in infants in developing countries in Asia: a randomised, double-blind, placebo-controlled trial](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20692031)

That are just a few results from a quick search, there are studies done for every approved vaccine. I'm using the US system as an example, but it will be similar in other countries. In the US [the FDA has to approve vaccines](http://www.fda.gov/biologicsbloodvaccines/developmentapprovalprocess/biologicslicenseapplicationsblaprocess/ucm133096.htm):

> Pre-marketing (pre-licensure) vaccine
>   clinical trials are typically done in
>   three phases, as is the case for any
>   drug or biologic. Initial human
>   studies, referred to as Phase 1, are
>   safety and immunogenicity studies
>   performed in a small number of closely
>   monitored subjects. Phase 2 studies
>   are dose-ranging studies and may
>   enroll hundreds of subjects. Finally,
>   Phase 3 trials typically enroll
>   thousands of individuals and provide
>   the critical documentation of
>   effectiveness and important additional
>   safety data required for licensing. At
>   any stage of the clinical or animal
>   studies, if data raise significant
>   concerns about either safety or
>   effectiveness, FDA may request
>   additional information or studies, or
>   may halt ongoing clinical studies.

So **any** vaccine will have to be shown safe and effective in clinical trials to get approved. They also continue to investigate the safety of the vaccines:

> The FDA continues to oversee the
>   production of vaccines after the
>   vaccine and the manufacturing
>   processes are approved, in order to
>   ensure continuing safety.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is "yes". Via PubMed:

- [Efficacy, safety, and immunogenicity of a Vero-cell-culture-derived trivalent influenza vaccine: a multicentre, double-blind, randomised, placebo-controlled trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21329971)
- [Amplified antigen-specific immune responses in HIV-1 infected individuals in a double blind DNA immunization and therapy interruption trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21300092)
- [Trivalent inactivated influenza vaccine in African adults infected with human immunodeficient virus: double blind, randomized clinical trial of efficacy, immunogenicity, and safety.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21148531)
- [Safety, immunogenicity and duration of protection of the RTS,S/AS02(D) malaria vaccine: one year follow-up of a randomized controlled phase I/IIb trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21079803)

Answer (score 4):

One study - http://www.accessexcellence.org/AE/AEC/CC/polio.php

Comment: That's not a study. It doesn't even contain the keywords study or peer-review

Comment: @Daniel, it's a summary of the polio vaccine and does discuss the studies used to validate it.

Comment: It doesn't reference any of the claims it makes. It isn't peer-reviewed. It doesn't contain any data. Some points for being published by a museum, I guess, but the OP asks for actual gold-standard studies.